# chain graph with vertices

Tags: diagrams

I'd like to draw the graph  via latex?

[image]

Comment: What's the name of this kind of graph? What do the labels a1, a2, etc. mean?

Comment: can we rotate a rectangle to get the desired result -- name the anchor points with labels

Comment: Why did you vandalize your question?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a short code,with `pstricks` (more precisely  the `pst-eucl` module):

```
 \documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}%
\begin{document}

    \begin{pspicture}(-6,-2)(6,5)\sffamily
    \psset{unit =1.5cm, dotsize=4pt, PtNameMath=false}
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={-90,90,90,60,-120,-90}](-4,2){a1}(-4,3){a2}(-3,3){a3}(-2,3){a4}(-2,2){a5}(-3,2){a6}
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={0,0,40,-140,180}](-1,2){b1}(-1,1){b2}(-1,0){b3}(-2,0){b4}(-2,1){b5}
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={90,140,-60,-90,-100}](0,0){c1}(1,0){c2}(1,-1){c3}(0,-1){c4}(-1,-1){c5}
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={180,180,0,0,40}](1,1){d1}(1,2){d2}(2,2){d3}(2,1){d4}(2,0){d5}
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={90,90,-90,-90,-90}](3,0){e1}(4,0){e2}(4,-1){e3}(3,-1){e4}(2,-1){e5}
    \foreach \i/\j in{a1/a4,b4/b1,c5/c2,c2/d3,e5/e2}{\psframe(\i)(\j)}
    \end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

*Some explanations*: \pstGeonode can create a list of points, given their coordinates and names. The name is automatically placed close to the point, in the direction PosAngle (default 0, i.e. on the right). The name is by default the name of the node and  typed in math mode.

[image]

*Edit*:  To print numbers for each node, it seems we can't give a number as Geonode name, so we need to use the key `PointName={...,...}` to print these numbers. Here is the explicit code:

```
\begin{pspicture}(-6,-2)(6,5)\sffamily \psset{unit =1.5cm, dotsize=4pt,
PtNameMath=false} 
\pstGeonode[PosAngle={-90,90,90,60,-120,-90}, PointName={1,2,3,4,5,6}] %
(-4,2){a1}(-4,3){a2}(-3,3){a3}(-2,3){a4}(-2,2){a5}(-3,2){a6}%
\pstGeonode[PosAngle={0,0,40,-140,180}, PointName={7,8,9,10,11}] %
(-1,2){b1}(-1,1){b2}(-1,0){b3}(-2,0){b4}(-2,1){b5}%
\pstGeonode[PosAngle={90,140,-60,-90,-100}, PointName={12,13,14,15,16}]%
(0,0){c1}(1,0){c2}(1,-1){c3}(0,-1){c4}(-1,-1){c5}%
\pstGeonode[PosAngle={180,180,0,0,40}, PointName={17,18,19,20,21}]%
(1,1){d1}(1,2){d2}(2,2){d3}(2,1){d4}(2,0){d5}%
 \pstGeonode[PosAngle={90,90,-90,-90,-90}, PointName={22,23,24,25,26}]%
(3,0){e1}(4,0){e2}(4,-1){e3}(3,-1){e4}(2,-1){e5}
%\foreach \i/\j in{1/4,10/7,16/13,13/19,26/23}{\psframe(\i)(\j)} \end{pspicture}
\foreach \i/\j in{a1/a4,b4/b1,c5/c2,c2/d3,e5/e2}{\psframe(\i)(\j)}%
\end{pspicture}
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean? Another way based on pstricks?

Comment: @Alfons To compile pstricks, you need to do the following compilation string `latex+dvips+ps2pdf`. Otherwise, all drawing packages like TikZ, asymptote, metapost, etc. can do the same thing.

Comment: @AndréC: The simplest is probably to compile with `xelatex`. You directly obtain the .pdf.

Comment: Probably, but I don't it well enough to tell you how to do that. `Pstricks` has the advantage of using a latex syntax.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do? Could you explain more?

Comment: I see. Did you also change the names  in `\foreach \i/\j in {a1/a4,b4/b1,...}`?

Comment: What you obtain?  A .pdf with only the dots and no line? Or do you have error messages?

Comment: It's not very clear. Not on the graphs means what? Could post the code you've tried? I've posted a self-contained code, does this one work?

Comment: @Alfons: The problem cam from the fact that `pst-eucl` doesn't seem to accept numbers as node names. Please see the solution to this problem in my edit.